# when creating an excel file from java do i need office installed on my system

Tags: java, xssf

When creating an excel file from java do i need office installed on my system?

I think java using its API must be able to create the .xls or .xlsx file. We will just not be able to open it?

If anyone know the answer please let me know.

Comment: Just try and you got your answer and update others. why r u asking such question when u able to find the answer. its your habit ?

Comment: `.xls` or `.xlsx` will be created fine, but you will not be able to open them without office.

Comment: you can create every file you want to. For Microsoft documents I would recommend using `Apache POI`. http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Excel application to create a .xls or .xlsx file using Java. However, to open the created file, you will need Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice Calc package.

You can use JXLS for creating a simple Excel sheet which is easy to use. This uses Apache POI in the backend. For very complex reports, Apache POI is preferred though, since Performance issues creep up in JXLS.

Comment: is it sufficent to have libreoffice package will it work with xlsx and apache poi ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you don't need any other application to process Excel files using Apache POI.